# print_at - use variable other than string

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

Is there a way to pass variable other than string to the print_at, from asciimatics library?

Description from the manual:

`print_at(text, x, y, colour=7, attr=0, bg=0, transparent=False)`
Print the text at the specified location using the specified colour and attributes.
Parameters

- text – The (single line) text to be printed.
- x – The column (x coord) for the start of the text.
- y – The line (y coord) for the start of the text.
- colour – The colour of the text to be displayed.
- attr – The cell attribute of the text to be displayed.
- bg – The background colour of the text to be displayed.
- transparent – Whether to print spaces or not, thus giving a transparent effect.

My code that I'm testing:

```
from asciimatics.screen import Screen

def print_test(screen):
    var1 = "string" #works
    var2 = int(2)   #error
    var3 = 3        #error
    var4 = [1,2,3]  #error
    var5 = (1,2,3)  #error
    screen.print_at(var1, 10, 10, 1, 1)
    screen.refresh()
    input()
Screen.wrapper(print_test)
```

Full code:
The program creates starting point represented by green "@" and then makes 10 moves, represented by yellow "@". What I want to achieve is change yellow "@" with numbers, to see in which order steps are made.

```
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
import os
import random

os.system('mode con: cols=51')


def exit_point():
    global exitX
    global exitY

    wall = random.randint(1,4)

    if wall == 1:
        exitX = random.randint(1,49)
        exitY = 0
    elif wall == 2:
        exitX = 49
        exitY = random.randint(1,49)
    elif wall == 3:
        exitX = random.randint(1,49)
        exitY = 49
    elif wall == 4:
        exitX = 0
        exitY = random.randint(1,49)


def start_point():
    global startX
    global startY

    startX = random.randint(2,48)
    startY = random.randint(2,48)


def setup(screen):
    screen.fill_polygon([[(0, 0), (50, 0), (50, 50), (0, 50)],[(1, 1), (49, 1), (49, 49), (1, 49)]])
    exit_point()
    screen.print_at("#", exitX, exitY, 1, 1)
    start_point()
    screen.print_at("@", startX, startY, 2, 1)
    screen.refresh()
    input()



def move(screen):
    #trace list
    trace = []

    #bring back setup screen, waste of code but more intuiative
    screen.fill_polygon([[(0, 0), (50, 0), (50, 50), (0, 50)],[(1, 1), (49, 1), (49, 49), (1, 49)]])
    screen.print_at("#", exitX, exitY, 1, 1)
    screen.print_at("@", startX, startY, 2, 1)


    #Add starting point to the list
    point = [startX,startY]
    trace.append(point)

    #1st move
    moveX = startX + random.randint(-1,1)
    moveY = startY + random.randint(-1,1)
    point = [moveX,moveY]
    trace.append(point)
    screen.print_at("@", moveX, moveY , 3, 1)

    #more moves
    moves = 1
    while moves < 10:
        moveX = moveX + random.randint(-1,1)
        moveY = moveY + random.randint(-1,1)
        point = [moveX,moveY]
        if point not in trace: 
            trace.append(point)
            screen.print_at("@", moveX, moveY , 3, 1)
            moves = moves + 1

    screen.refresh()
    input()

Screen.wrapper(setup)
Screen.wrapper(move)
input()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like `print_at` accepts anything other than a sequence of characters. But you could convert your value to string before passing it to the function.

```
screen.print_at(str(var4), 10, 10, 1, 1)
```

If you're thinking "ok, but it would be inconvenient to change all my `print_at` calls to use `str()`", you could create a subclass of `Screen` that does it for you automatically.

```
class PermissiveScreen(Screen):
    def print_at(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().print_at(str(text), *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like solution. I edited my main code as you suggested and it created a nice line of steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer to your exact question is "no, you cannot".
**However**, this does not mean you cannot achieve the goal you are describing.
Why not convert the number about to be printed by `print_at` into a string, when passing it as an argument?

like this in your larger code

```
def print_test(screen):
    var1 = "string" #works
    var2 = int(2)   #error
    var3 = 3        #error # Let's try to pass this
    var4 = [1,2,3]  #error
    var5 = (1,2,3)  #error
    screen.print_at(str(var3), 10, 10, 1, 1) # Here is the conversion
    screen.refresh()
    input()
Screen.wrapper(print_test)
```

Comment: Yes, It's working as you suggested. Thanks Ilia for help :)

Comment: nie ma za co :)